# How to map a complex Python object to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, mapping

I have a Json file that I read into Python as an object. The json file as follows:

```
{
  "ID": "1",
  "Container": {
    "DistributionOptions": [
      {
        "OptionId": 1,
        "OptionSet": [
          {
            "Location": {
              "Number": "1"
            },
            "Lines": [
              {
                "OrderLineId": 0,
                "Quantity": 2
              },
              {
                "OrderLineId": 1,
                "Quantity": 4
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Location": {
              "Number": "2"
            },
            "Lines": [
              {
                "OrderLineId": 2,
                "Quantity": 5
              },
              {
                "OrderLineId": 3,
                "Quantity": 7
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "OptionId": 2,
        "OptionSet": [
          {
            "Location": {
              "Number": "3"
            },
            "Lines": [
              {
                "OrderLineId": 0,
                "Quantity": 2
              },
              {
                "OrderLineId": 1,
                "Quantity": 4
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Location": {
              "Number": "4"
            },
            "Lines": [
              {
                "OrderLineId": 2,
                "Quantity": 5
              },
              {
                "OrderLineId": 3,
                "Quantity": 7
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The json file is read in a python object as follows:

```
python_object = json.loads(raw, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
```

Now, I want to transform 'python_object' starting from the node 'DistributionOptions' in a pandas dataframe where the higher level attributes are repeated for each lower level attribute or list element.

I want to prevent unnecessary for loops due to efficiency constraints. So far I have tried the map object with a custom function but then I would lose some higher level attributes.

Any idea on how to flatten/map this python object (or json directly) with (nested) lists of objects into the following dataframe?

| OptionId | Location | OrderlineId | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 7 |

Comment: Is the example json you shared your entire json file?

Comment: Any list inside this json may contain an arbitrary number of elements. Other than that I have removed a few nodes which are currently not in scope but may be required later in the project.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this.

```
# path to your json file
p = Path(r'path/to/your/file.json')

# read json
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    jsonRecord = json.loads(f.read())

# Extract `DistributionOptions` since you need to start from the node 'DistributionOptions'
data= jsonRecord["Container"]["DistributionOptions"]
# json_normalize
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['OptionSet','Lines'], meta=['OptionId',['OptionSet','Location', 'Number']], errors='ignore')
```

Output:

```
         OrderLineId  Quantity  OptionId OptionSet.Location.Number
0            0         2        1                         1
1            1         4        1                         1
2            2         5        1                         2
3            3         7        1                         2
4            0         2        2                         3
5            1         4        2                         3
6            2         5        2                         4
7            3         7        2                         4
```

However, a different approach would be needed if you have multiple `ID` `Container` pairs in your json.